# My preg_replace also replacing linebreak why?

Tags: php, html

i do not want my preg_replace to replace line break, here is my code

```
preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $message_ins);
```

Eg:

```
X
Y 
Z
```

output is `XYZ`

i want it to be same as

```
X 
Y 
Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line break is normally represented by a linefeed, `\x0A`.  Since that's just a character, and it's outside the range `\x20`-`\x7F`, it gets replaced.  If you don't want it replaced, you need to add it to the character class. You probably want to add the carriage return character `\x0D`, too, just in case you wind up dealing with text files that have passed through Windows:

```
preg_replace('/[^\x20-\x7F\x0A\x0D]*/','', $message_ins);
```

Note that the parentheses in your version are redundant, because they're already included in the range. If you were trying to do something other than include the characters `(` and `)` in the negated character class, then you've made a mistake and need to revisit that.

Comment: My main aim is replace all unicode characters from my text, i had tried ur code its working OR do u suggest me any other code(preg_replace) which will be the best for me.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are excluding every character not in the range \x20-\x7F from the class you are using for comparasion.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply,this preg_replace is to replace all unicode characters,than what would be the preg_replace for it